# JBPM 6.5 How to avoid human task auto assignment

Tags: task, jbpm

I know that JBPM 6 has a special behavior when we use swimlanes and human tasks (part 7.2.1): https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.5.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html/ch07.html 
Is it possible to avoid human tasks to be assigned to user that completes fist human task in swimlane? I want to assign all tasks in swimlane to a GroupId.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best option is not to use swimlane. This is what I did in production. Instead, using this to replace swimlane, I know it doesn't seem pretty. However, this is the workaround I did.

[image]